# When are the continuous functions generated by the coordinate functions?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

My question may be a little vague so I gladly take any advice on how to make it more precise or 'better'.

If we are in a compact metric space $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (as an example) we can look at the continuous functions over $A$. This is a $C^*$-Algebra. We can also look at the $n$ coordinate functions on $A$. My question would be: When is the algebra generated by the coordinate functions equal to $C(A)$? This seems to be the case for example for the sphere, but if i take a finite space you seem to need at least as many dimensions as your space has points. But I'm not really sure about that or even how to get more general statements.

Does someone have an idea or some results? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just the coordinate functions? No constants? And what norm do you use if $A$ is the whole space?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, i think I'd prefer just the coordinate functions. But if there are ideas for the same with putting the 1 into it, I'm open. The examples i looked at often give you the 1 for free. As a norm I'm thinking of the standard euclidean norm. Or am i misunderstanding the question? Ah, know that i'm thinking... i guess the whole space doesn't work.

Comment: @zhw. Now i understand you. Edited 'compact' into the question. Now i understand you; doesn't make much sense otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algebra generated by the coordinate functions is just the set of polynomials that vanish at $0.$ So if $0\notin A,$ you will get density in $C(A)$ by Stone-Weierstrass, otherwise you'll get density in the continuous functions on $A$ that vanish at $0,$ again using S-W.

Comment: Ok, then i'm not understanding something very basic. If $A$ is just the space consisting of the points $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$, then the coordinate function(s) just generates $\mathbb{C}$, doesn't it? But $C(A)$ should be $\mathbb{C}^2$? What am i mixing up here?

Comment: You'll have all $ax +bx^2$ in the coordinate function algebra, so it looks like $\mathbb C^2$ to me.

Comment: Ok, S-W definitely gives me the right answer, thanks. But how can i interpret the coordinate functions as polynomials? What does for example $x^2$ mean here?

Comment: $x$ is a coordinate function, and so $x^2$ is in the algebra.